# PC freezes randomly with no activity

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze, windows-10-v2004

It started few days (not immediately) after I upgraded to Windows 2004. And it seems to be getting worse everyday.

My PC will freeze in middle of work randomly. I think it doesn't happen when it's idle. Both keyboard, mouse will stop working, screen will freeze, as well sound also stops.

What I tried so far:

- Event Viewer: Nothing there at all.
- Uninstalled PrimoCache, re-install graphics driver, dedicated graphics, bluetooth, wireless.
- Opened back cover of laptop and re-installed RAM, Hard disk and SSD after cleaning them.

So far nothing has worked and I am getting out of things to try. Where should I look? I can't be 100% right but it's getting worsen everyday. Maybe it's a hardware problem?

Comment: Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: @DavidPostill Ok. It might sound strange. But I have paper stuff in battery compartment because it was loose. Once I removed them all, the issue seem to have resolved.